# Power maps of contractible topological groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm little bit puzzled  with the following question, I was wondering if someone could help with a suggestion or a hint.

Let start with some notations. Suppose that $G$ is a Hausdorff  topological group such that

1. As a space $G$ is contractible.
2. As a group $G$ is isomorphic to the free product  $\mathrm{Q}\ast F(X) $ where $\mathrm{Q}$ is the additive abelian group of rational numbers and $F(X)$ is a free group generated by a set $X$.
3. We assume that $\mathrm{Q}$ is a topological subgroup of $G$ in an obvious way and that $H=\{1\}\ast_{\mathrm{Q}} G$ is a retract of a free topological group (generated by a CW-complex).

Let $\mathbf{Ab}: \mathsf{Tgr}\rightarrow \mathsf{AbTgr}$ be the abelianization functor from the category of topological groups to abelian topological groups.

Since $G$ is a contractible group, for any natural number $n>0$ the power maps $p^{n}: G\rightarrow G$, $t\mapsto t^n$ are weak homotopy equivalences of underlying topological spaces.

My question is the following: is there a hope that the power maps: $p^{n}: \mathbf{Ab}(G)\rightarrow \mathbf{Ab}(G)$ induce weak homotopy equivalences of underlying topological spaces? The same question of $H$ and power maps  $p^{n}: H\rightarrow H$, are they weak homotopy equivalences ?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing such a $G$. For one thing, a Hausdorff contractible space is uncountable, so I guess the set $X$ must be uncountable (and have an interesting topology). For another, you say that $G$ is an amalgamated product of $Q$ and $F(X)$ but do not mention what subgroup it's amalgamated over. Could you give an example of such a $G$?

Comment: This a list of questions rather than a helpful comment. (1) Are there example of such $G$ for some specific examples of $X$? So, what is $G$ if $X=\{a,b\}$ or $X=\mathbb{R}$. (2) As to the above comment, do the above desired properties of $G$ depends on whether or not $X$ is countable or not? (3) If you choose $X$ to be a finite set then is there any reason to believe that the truth of `hope' depends on the divisibility of $|X|$ by $p$ or $n$?

Comment: @KevinCasto roughly speaking, an ideal example is homotopy theoretical, take $\mathrm{Q}\rightarrow \ast$ the obvious homomorphism of groups. There is a factorization $Q\rightarrow G\rightarrow \ast$ where the first map is a cofibration (of topological groups) and the second map is a trivial fibration.

Comment: @user51223 I just wrote a comment of an ideal example. in that case my question has a positive answer. the set X has not to be countable in general.

Comment: @IliasAmrani What is the set $X$ in this case, and what topology does it have? Why is $G$ the (amalgamated? over what?) free product of $Q$ and $F(X)$?

Comment: @KevinCasto There is a model structure on the category of topological groups, where weak equivalence (fibrations) are weak homotopy equivalence (serre fibrations) of underlying spaces. cofibrant objects are topological groups which are retracts of free topological groups (generated on retract of CW-complexes). in particular the underlying group of a cofibrant topological groups are free groups. So in the ideal example we can factor the trivial map $Q\rightarrow \ast$ by $Q\rightarrow G\rightarrow \ast$ where the first map is a cofibration of topological groups and the second is ...

Comment: @KevinCasto a trivial fibration. Hence G is trivial as space an $Q\ast F(X)$ as a group for some set X. I need to be more precise may be about cofibrant objects, but let say that the idea is quasi correct

Comment: Are there examples of contractible topological groups whose abelianizations are not contractible?

Comment: @TimCampion a short answer: If a contractible topological group is not "cofibrant" there is no reason that its abelianization  is contractible.

Comment: @IliasA. I'm willing to believe that if $G$ is a non-cofibrant topological group which is _weakly_ contractible, then its abelianization need not be weakly contractible. But do you have an example of a topological group which is actually _contractible_ whose abelianization is not contractible? I'm doubting that such a thing exists, because I suspect that abelianization takes homotopies to homotopies.

Comment: @TimCampion I'm little bit confused, in my question the condition is that the topological group is contractibe as a space (not as a topological group). Your comment suggests that you are talking about a topological group contractible as a topological group, then I do agree that its abelianization is also contractible.

Comment: No, I’m talking about contractibility as a space versus having all homotopy groups vanish.

Comment: @TimCampion Then I do not think that the abelianization preserves such homotopies.

Comment: @IliasA. But is this just something you think, or do you have a counterexample?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93493/discussion-between-ilias-a-and-tim-campion).

Comment: I have undeleted this question which you have deleted last year. -- Please do not self-delete your useful questions!